# How to fix "Array.prototype.filter()" warning in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React, my code works, but there is this warning I could not fix. Here is the problem, I filtered my data in React like this:

```
{data.asset ? data.asset.filter((value) => {
     if (something === "") {
          return (
              <Card>
                  <Card.Body>
                      <Card.Text>
                          Something: {value}
                      </Card.Text>
                  </Card.Body>
              </Card>
           );
      }
      else {
         return (
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Text>
                         Something: {value}
                    </Card.Text>
                 </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          );
       });
```

I understand that the warning

```
"Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function"
```

means that I need to have a return statement outside of the if/else statement. However, nothing I try works if I return another card outside the if/else statement then my if/else statement will stop working properly. So I figured what if I return an empty return statement like:

```
return;
```

Same thing, my if/else statement will then stop working properly.

I honestly don't know how to fix this warning, I could ignore it but I want to learn and improve on my knowledge, Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to achieve with the `.filter` and the JSX there?

Comment: Seems like you might want to be using a `map` instead of `filter`

Comment: Sorry, I might have shortened the code too much. I have this search bar, I tried to filter whatever the user input to match up with the database. So now, if the user inputs nothing then it will go through the if statement
`
if (something === "") {}
`
then it will display all the data as cards. The else statement is actually written as follow
<code>
else if (value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toString().toLowerCase())) {
</code>
Then it will display whatever user input like "car" then it will try to filter the data to look for "car" then display car.

Comment: I think what you want is `data.asset.filter((value) => !searchTerm || value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toString().toLowerCase()).map((value)=>/**wrap your value in a card here **/)`. Filter removes non matching elements from an array. Map creates an array based on another array. This is what Nick was saying.